# Avoid redefinition error in template class

Tags: c++, c++11

For IO purposes, I need to associate to various type a character string. To this end, I created a template class `names`, which is specialized for each type I need to name. Here is the header file:

```
template<typename T>
class names {};

template<>
class names<Index> {
public:
    static const std::string name;
};

template<>
class names<Integer> {
public:
    static const std::string name;
};
```

And the corresponding source file:

```
const std::string names<Index>::name = "Index";

const std::string names<Integer>::name = "Integer";
```

`Index` and `Integer` are defined via a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::ptrdiff_t Index;

typedef int Integer;
```

The code compiles and runs fine on the macOS and Ubuntu machines I use. However, on a Windows machine, `std::ptrdiff_t` is defined as an `int`. I then get the following error:

```
In file included from lib/mixt_MixtComp.h:22:0,
                 from dummy.cpp:5:
lib/LinAlg/names.h:28:7: error: redefinition of 'class mixt::names<int>'
 class names<Integer> {
       ^
lib/LinAlg/names.h:22:7: error: previous definition of 'class mixt::names<int>'
 class names<Index> {
       ^
```

Is there a way to avoid this error ? I can use C++11.

Comment: No, it's not `int` *on Windows*. It's `int` with your 32-bit compiler which happens to run on Windows. It will be `int` on Linux too if you compile in 32-bit mode. On 64-bit systems, `ptrdiff_t` is `long` so you will get the same error when you add `long` to your bag of types. You cannot avoid this because `ptrdiff_t` is not a type, it's just a name for a type. Whether the problem can be fixed largely depends on what you are trying to do with these specialisations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. On Windows, pick just the one specialisation and don't define the other one. (Ew.)
2. What you really need here is a *strong typedef*, rather than just a thin type alias. You need `Index` and `Integer` to be actually different types, rather than just names for something else that might be the same in both cases.

   If you don't mind a bit of an arseache when it comes to using these types for arithmetic, a scoped enum may be appropriate:

   ```
   enum class Index   : std::ptrdiff_t {};
   enum class Integer : int {};
   ```

   Now the two types are distinct but "inherit" from what you want them to be, and they won't conflict or even implicitly convert to one another. It'll work [on your UNIXy platforms](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bde1a5f97588977), and [on your Windows box](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/521dde11f2a2c5f4).

   Indeed, if these types are not *supposed* to be used arithmetically, then the properties of a scoped enum are actually spot on.

In general I would tend to avoid `typedef`. It has its uses for shortening long names (although prefer `using X = Y` nowadays for clarity), but for almost anything else you're begging for just the sort of trouble that you've found here.

Comment: You're right, there isn't really a way to distinguish them when those are just alias, so no clean solution... My poor attempt deleted... +1

Comment: Would this solution penalyze the performances of my program compared the typedef ?

Comment: @vkubicki No, types are a purely compile-time construct and your values hold the same underlying type as they did before. Of course without being able to see _any_ of your runtime usage of these types I can't make strong promises, but for any such question you should _measure it_.

Comment: Regarding the usage, I have cases which do not compile using enum, like Index nbInd = data.size();, where data.size() returns an unsigned long, and comes from an external library. Will external libraries forbid me to use your solution ?

Comment: @vkubicki No, probably not, you just need to cast. Please turn to the chapter in your C++ book regarding scoped enums.